# Error goes like this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 at Percolation.main

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, grid

I'm having trouble with this particular programa using the Weighted Quick UnionFind loop. Can anyone clear up why this error appears? How can I fix this? I've tried to change arguments here, but the error is still unresolved.

Is it within in Percolation(), or the main argument itself? Please enlighten me, it's been a while since I had this kind of programming problem.

```java
    import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.WeightedQuickUnionUF;
    import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;
    import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;
    import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
    import java.lang.*;


    public class Percolation {
    int n;
    private boolean[][] grid;
    private WeightedQuickUnionUF uf;
    int openSites;


    // creates n-by-n grid, with all sites initially blocked
    public Percolation(int n) {
        this.n = n;
        this.uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n * n + 2);
        this.grid = new boolean[n][n];
        for (int row = 0; row <= n; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col <= n; col++)
            {
              grid[row][col] = false;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
         uf.union (n * n, i);
        }
        this.openSites = 0;
    }
    // opens the site (row, col) if it is not open already
    public void open(int row, int col)
    {
        if ((row < 0 || col < 0) && (row >= n || col >= n)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value must be above 0!");
        }
        if(!(this.grid[row][col])){
            this.grid[row][col] = true;
            openSites++;
        }
        if (isOpen(row - 1, col)) { // open left
            uf.union(convert2D(row, col), convert2D(row - 1, col));
        }
        if (isOpen(row + 1, col)) { // open right
            uf.union(convert2D(row, col), convert2D(row + 1, col));
        }
        if (isOpen(row, col + 1)) { // open down
            uf.union(convert2D(row, col), convert2D(row, col + 1));
        }
        if (isOpen(row, col - 1)) { // open up
            uf.union(convert2D(row, col), convert2D(row, col - 1));
        }

    }
    // is the site (row, col) open?
    public boolean isOpen(int row, int col)
    {
        if ((row < 0 || col < 0) && (row >= n || col >= n)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value must be above 0!");
        }

        return grid[row][col];
    }
    // is the site (row, col) full?
    public boolean isFull(int row, int col)
    { ;
        if ((row < 0 || col < 0) && (row >= n || col >= n)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value must be above 0!");
        }

        if (isOpen(row, col)){
            if (uf.find(row + col * n) == uf.find(n * n)) return true;
        }

        return uf.find(n * n) == uf.find(convert2D(row, col) - 1);
    }
    // returns the number of open sites
    public int numberOfOpenSites()
    {
        return openSites;
    }

    // turns [row][cool] coordinates to uf values
    private int convert2D(int row, int col){
        return (n * row) + col + 1;
    }

    // does the system percolate?
    public boolean percolates()
    { return uf.find(n * n) == uf.find (n * n + 1); }
    // test client (optional)
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
         Percolation perc = new Percolation(x);
         int testTrials = 1;
         int argsCount = args.length;
         for (int i = 1; argsCount >= 2; i += 2)
         {
             int row = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
             int col = Integer.parseInt(args[i + 1]);

             perc.open(row, col);
             if (perc.percolates()){
                 StdOut.println("The system percolates.");
             }

             argsCount -= 2;
         }
         if (!perc.percolates()){
             StdOut.println("The system does not percolate.");
         }

}

}
```

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that the code, as is, doesn't even compile, where in the code does the error happen?

Comment: Why doesn't it compile? It happens in Line 95

Comment: When I made that comment there was a syntax error that someone [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63850946/revisions) (see revision 2). Anyway, by my count line 95 is `int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);`, so that error means you're not passing any argument to your program.